# I would like to change my Items Page from using CollectionView to ListView in xamarin.forms but I am having issues?

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

The above header refers.

I would like to make this change so I can implement expanding lists (whereby my some of my list of items could have sub-items that can appear and disappear when you tap on their parent item).

But, when I am trying to test the app, a hitherto hidden page appeared with several new errors.  I now know this file is auto-generated.

How do I successfully convert a working collectionview code to listview?

The collection View code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Abuse_Alert.Views.ItemsPage"
             Title="{Binding Title}"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Abuse_Alert.ViewModels"  
             xmlns:model="clr-namespace:Abuse_Alert.Models"  
             x:Name="BrowseItemsPage">

    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <!-- 
       <ToolbarItem Text="Add" Command="{Binding AddItemCommand}" />
        -->
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <!--
      x:DataType enables compiled bindings for better performance and compile time validation of binding expressions.
      https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/compiled-bindings
    -->
    <RefreshView x:DataType="local:ItemsViewModel" Command="{Binding LoadItemsCommand}" IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <CollectionView x:Name="ItemsListView"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                SelectionMode="None" IsGrouped="False">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout Padding="10" x:DataType="model:Item">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Text}" 
                            LineBreakMode="NoWrap" 
                            Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" 
                            FontSize="16" />
                        <Label Text="{Binding Description}" 
                            LineBreakMode="NoWrap"
                            Style="{DynamicResource ListItemDetailTextStyle}"
                            FontSize="13" />
                        <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer 
                                NumberOfTapsRequired="1"
                                Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource 
                                 AncestorType={x:Type local:ItemsViewModel}}, Path=ItemTapped}"     
                                CommandParameter="{Binding .}">
                            </TapGestureRecognizer>
                        </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                    </StackLayout>
                 </DataTemplate>
               </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
             </CollectionView>
           </RefreshView>
        </ContentPage>
```

This is the ListView Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Abuse_Alert.Views.ItemsPage"
             Title="{Binding Title}"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Abuse_Alert.ViewModels"  
             xmlns:model="clr-namespace:Abuse_Alert.Models"  
             x:Name="BrowseItemsPage">

    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <!-- 
       <ToolbarItem Text="Add" Command="{Binding AddItemCommand}" />
        -->
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <!--
      x:DataType enables compiled bindings for better performance and compile time validation of binding expressions.
      https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/compiled-bindings
    -->
    <Grid>
        <StackLayout x:Name="local:ItemsViewModel" Padding="1,0,1,0">
            <ListView x:Name="ItemsListView"
                BackgroundColor="White"
                IsGroupingEnabled="True"
                IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true"
                IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                RefreshCommand="{Binding LoadItemsCommand}"     
                SelectionMode="None" 
                >
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout Padding="10" x:DataType="model:Item">
                                <Label Text="{Binding Text}" 
                                 LineBreakMode="NoWrap" 
                                 Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" 
                                 FontSize="16" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding Description}" 
                                 LineBreakMode="NoWrap"
                                 Style="{DynamicResource ListItemDetailTextStyle}"
                                 FontSize="13" />
                                <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer 
                                    NumberOfTapsRequired="1"
                                    Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:ItemsViewModel}}, Path=ItemTapped}"     
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding .}">
                                    </TapGestureRecognizer>
                                </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                            </StackLayout>
                         </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

This is the correct auto-generated file (with CollectionView):

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.42000
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

[assembly: global::Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlResourceIdAttribute("AbuseAlert.Views.ItemsPage.xaml", "Views/ItemsPage.xaml", typeof(global::Abuse_Alert.Views.ItemsPage))]

namespace Abuse_Alert.Views {
    
    
    [global::Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlFilePathAttribute("Views\\ItemsPage.xaml")]
    public partial class ItemsPage : global::Xamarin.Forms.ContentPage {
        
        [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlG", "2.0.0.0")]
        private global::Xamarin.Forms.ContentPage BrowseItemsPage;
        
        [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlG", "2.0.0.0")]
        private global::Xamarin.Forms.CollectionView ItemsListView;
        
        [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlG", "2.0.0.0")]
        private void InitializeComponent() {
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.Extensions.LoadFromXaml(this, typeof(ItemsPage));
            BrowseItemsPage = global::Xamarin.Forms.NameScopeExtensions.FindByName<global::Xamarin.Forms.ContentPage>(this, "BrowseItemsPage");
            ItemsListView = global::Xamarin.Forms.NameScopeExtensions.FindByName<global::Xamarin.Forms.CollectionView>(this, "ItemsListView");
        }
    }
}
```

This is the auto-generated file (with listview):

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.42000
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

[assembly: global::Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlResourceIdAttribute("AbuseAlert.Views.ItemsPage.xaml", "Views/ItemsPage.xaml", typeof(global::Abuse_Alert.Views.ItemsPage))]

namespace Abuse_Alert.Views {
    
    
    [global::Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlFilePathAttribute("Views\\ItemsPage.xaml")]
    public partial class ItemsPage : global::Xamarin.Forms.ContentPage {
        
        [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlG", "2.0.0.0")]
        private global::Xamarin.Forms.ContentPage BrowseItemsPage;
        
        [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlG", "2.0.0.0")]
        private global::Xamarin.Forms.StackLayout local:ItemsViewModel;
        
        [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlG", "2.0.0.0")]
        private global::Xamarin.Forms.ListView ItemsListView;
        
        [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlG", "2.0.0.0")]
        private void InitializeComponent() {
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.Extensions.LoadFromXaml(this, typeof(ItemsPage));
            BrowseItemsPage = global::Xamarin.Forms.NameScopeExtensions.FindByName<global::Xamarin.Forms.ContentPage>(this, "BrowseItemsPage");
            local:ItemsViewModel = global::Xamarin.Forms.NameScopeExtensions.FindByName<global::Xamarin.Forms.StackLayout>(this, "local:ItemsViewModel");
            ItemsListView = global::Xamarin.Forms.NameScopeExtensions.FindByName<global::Xamarin.Forms.ListView>(this, "ItemsListView");
        }
    }
}
```

These are the errors when i changed the code to listview:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1003  Syntax error, ',' expected  AbuseAlert  D:\MobileApps\SVr\SVReporting - Backup\SV Reporting\obj\Debug\netstandard2.0\Views\ItemsPage.xaml.g.cs  23  Active
Error   CS1002  ; expected  AbuseAlert  D:\MobileApps\SVr\SVReporting - Backup\SV Reporting\obj\Debug\netstandard2.0\Views\ItemsPage.xaml.g.cs  23  Active
Error   CS1519  Invalid token ';' in class, record, struct, or interface member declaration AbuseAlert  D:\MobileApps\SVr\SVReporting - Backup\SV Reporting\obj\Debug\netstandard2.0\Views\ItemsPage.xaml.g.cs  23  Active
Error   CS1519  Invalid token ';' in class, record, struct, or interface member declaration AbuseAlert  D:\MobileApps\SVr\SVReporting - Backup\SV Reporting\obj\Debug\netstandard2.0\Views\ItemsPage.xaml.g.cs  23  Active
Error   CS0006  Metadata file 'D:\MobileApps\SVr\SVReporting - Backup\SV Reporting\obj\Debug\netstandard2.0\ref\AbuseAlert.dll' could not be found  AbuseAlert.Android  D:\MobileApps\SVr\SVReporting - Backup\SV Reporting.Android\CSC 1   Active
Error   IDE1007 The name 'ItemsViewModel' does not exist in the current context.    AbuseAlert  D:\MobileApps\SVr\SVReporting - Backup\SV Reporting\obj\Debug\netstandard2.0\Views\ItemsPage.xaml.g.cs  23  Active
Error   CS0103  The name 'ItemsViewModel' does not exist in the current context AbuseAlert  D:\MobileApps\SVr\SVReporting - Backup\SV Reporting\obj\Debug\netstandard2.0\Views\ItemsPage.xaml.g.cs  32  Active
Warning CS0164  This label has not been referenced  AbuseAlert  D:\MobileApps\SVr\SVReporting - Backup\SV Reporting\obj\Debug\netstandard2.0\Views\ItemsPage.xaml.g.cs  32  Active

This is the ListView code that is not properly displaying the Item & its related description. But if I reduce Item to size 10 & Description to size 8, both will appear correctly but will appear too small.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Abuse_Alert.Views.ItemsPage"
             Title="{Binding Title}"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Abuse_Alert.ViewModels"  
             xmlns:model="clr-namespace:Abuse_Alert.Models"  
             x:Name="BrowseItemsPage">

    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <!-- 
       <ToolbarItem Text="Add" Command="{Binding AddItemCommand}" />
        -->
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <!--
      x:DataType enables compiled bindings for better performance and compile time validation of binding expressions.
      https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/compiled-bindings
    -->
    <RefreshView x:DataType="local:ItemsViewModel" Command="{Binding LoadItemsCommand}" IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=TwoWay}">
        <ListView x:Name="ItemsListView" 
                BackgroundColor="White"
                IsGroupingEnabled="false"
                IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true"
                IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=TwoWay}"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                HasUnevenRows="True" 
                RowHeight="48"
                SelectionMode="None" 
            >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Padding="10" x:DataType="model:Item" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Vertical">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Text}" TextColor="Black" 
                            LineBreakMode="NoWrap" 
                            Style="{DynamicResource ListItemTextStyle}" 
                            FontSize="16" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding Description}" TextColor="Black" 
                            LineBreakMode="NoWrap"
                            Style="{DynamicResource ListItemDetailTextStyle}"
                            FontSize="13" />
                            <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer 
                                NumberOfTapsRequired="1"
                                Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:ItemsViewModel}}, Path=ItemTapped}"     
                                CommandParameter="{Binding .}">
                                </TapGestureRecognizer>
                            </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </RefreshView>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Show the collectionview code you want to convert. Show the listview code you tried, that didn’t work. Show exactly what errors happened. Show the code you would like to use to expand subitems. OR Read about DataTemplateSelector - perhaps you can do what you want, in your collectionview.

Comment: "several new errors" - we can't help you if you can't be bothered to provide more information than this

Comment: I have now added the codes to my original post. Sorry, I was having issue specifying the codes and I was pressed to go somewhere that's why i had to post it like that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

this should not be difficult

```
<ListView x:Name="ItemsListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" >
   <ListView.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
       <ViewCell>
         .. StackLayout goes here ..
       </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Thanks, Jason. This one has worked. No errors and successful deployment to my emulator. Let me now integrate the sub-list and see how it turns out. I will definitely revert very soon.

Comment: How do I get my stacklayout to display properly? Is there a way to resize each item displayed to accomodate the Name and Desccription? Right now, only the Name is appearing fully while the description is appearing partly. Under the CollectionView, everything appeared very well.

Comment: Try to add property `HasUnevenRows="True"`  in your ListView.

Comment: Hi Jason. This issue is still pending. Thanks.

Comment: try assigning a height value to your layout

Comment: I have done both, HasUnevenRows="True" and Heightrequested="48", yet no show.

Comment: I have updated my initial question by adding the listview code at the bottom. Thanks. However, I just tried making RowHeight="48" and it is now appearing correctly.